# T902: Autorotate screen

Tags: 13.10, fujitsu-siemens

I have a Fujitsu T902 and have several problems. I guess I'll split them up into different questions. I have installed 13.10 Ubuntu, uname -a tells me:

> 3.11.0-13-generic #20-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 23 07:38:26 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Since the laptop is a convertible I want to change rotation when the screen is flipped resp. when I change the position. So, on the one hand the question for rotating the screen itself, on the other hand the question for changing position similar to a mobile device where you can change landscape and portrait mode easily.

I tried with Magick, but somehow failed with that approach:

```
 leo@leo-LIFEBOOK-T902:~ ./magick-rotation
Please install 62-magick.rules in /etc/udev/rules.d.
See INSTALLER.txt in the unpacked magick-rotation folder.
leo@leo-LIFEBOOK-T902:~/Downloads/magick-rotation-1.6.2$ ll /etc/ud
udev/    udisks2/ 
leo@leo-LIFEBOOK-T902:~/Downloads/magick-rotation-1.6.2$ ll /etc/udev/rules.d/
insgesamt 20
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 14 15:42 ./
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Okt 16 20:59 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  937 Nov 14 15:42 62-magick.rules
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  632 Nov 14 12:59 70-persistent-net.rules
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1157 Okt 12 13:01 README
```

So, my question is if there is a chance to get the rotation recognition working? I don't mind if its Magick or not. But would be great if the additional sensors and the swivel hinge could be used to detect position changes....